# Detect STM32L442 USB disconnection

Tags: usb, stm32

I'm developing a project that uses STM32L442KC and I can't detect when USB device mode is disconnected (USB cable unplugged).

What can I do to detect USB disconnection? Is there some interruption? Or do I need check some flag?

---

**Update:**

Below is the IRQ Handler generated by STM32CubeMX. It doesn't have the **HAL_PCD_DisconnectCallback** callback and **HAL_PCD_SuspendCallback** isn't called when the cable is unplugged.

```c
void HAL_PCD_IRQHandler(PCD_HandleTypeDef *hpcd)
{
  uint32_t wInterrupt_Mask = 0;

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_CTR))
  {
    /* servicing of the endpoint correct transfer interrupt */
    /* clear of the CTR flag into the sub */
    PCD_EP_ISR_Handler(hpcd);
  }

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_RESET))
  {
    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_RESET);
    HAL_PCD_ResetCallback(hpcd);
    HAL_PCD_SetAddress(hpcd, 0);
  }

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_PMAOVR))
  {
    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_PMAOVR);    
  }

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_ERR))
  {
    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_ERR); 
  }

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_WKUP))
  {

    hpcd->Instance->CNTR &= ~(USB_CNTR_LPMODE);

    /*set wInterrupt_Mask global variable*/
    wInterrupt_Mask = USB_CNTR_CTRM  | USB_CNTR_WKUPM | USB_CNTR_SUSPM | USB_CNTR_ERRM \
      | USB_CNTR_SOFM | USB_CNTR_ESOFM | USB_CNTR_RESETM;

    /*Set interrupt mask*/
    hpcd->Instance->CNTR = wInterrupt_Mask;

    /* enable L1REQ interrupt */ 
    if (hpcd->Init.lpm_enable ==1)
    {
      wInterrupt_Mask |= USB_CNTR_L1REQM;

      /* Enable LPM support and enable ACK answer to LPM request*/
      USB_TypeDef *USBx = hpcd->Instance;
      hpcd->lpm_active = ENABLE;
      hpcd->LPM_State = LPM_L0;

      USBx->LPMCSR |= (USB_LPMCSR_LMPEN);
      USBx->LPMCSR |= (USB_LPMCSR_LPMACK);
    } 

    if(hpcd->LPM_State == LPM_L1)
    {
      hpcd->LPM_State = LPM_L0;
      HAL_PCDEx_LPM_Callback(hpcd, PCD_LPM_L0_ACTIVE);
    }

    HAL_PCD_ResumeCallback(hpcd);

    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_WKUP);     
  }

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_SUSP))
  {    
    /* clear of the ISTR bit must be done after setting of CNTR_FSUSP */
    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_SUSP);  

    /* Force low-power mode in the macrocell */
    hpcd->Instance->CNTR |= USB_CNTR_FSUSP;
    hpcd->Instance->CNTR |= USB_CNTR_LPMODE;

    if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_WKUP) == 0)
    {
      HAL_PCD_SuspendCallback(hpcd);
    }
  }

  /* Handle LPM Interrupt */ 
  if(__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_L1REQ))
  {
    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_L1REQ);      
    if( hpcd->LPM_State == LPM_L0)
    {   
      /* Force suspend and low-power mode before going to L1 state*/
      hpcd->Instance->CNTR |= USB_CNTR_LPMODE;
      hpcd->Instance->CNTR |= USB_CNTR_FSUSP;

      hpcd->LPM_State = LPM_L1;
      hpcd->BESL = (hpcd->Instance->LPMCSR & USB_LPMCSR_BESL) >>2 ;  
      HAL_PCDEx_LPM_Callback(hpcd, PCD_LPM_L1_ACTIVE);
    }
    else
    {
      HAL_PCD_SuspendCallback(hpcd);
    }
  }

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_SOF))
  {
    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_SOF); 
    HAL_PCD_SOFCallback(hpcd);
  }

  if (__HAL_PCD_GET_FLAG (hpcd, USB_ISTR_ESOF))
  {
    /* clear ESOF flag in ISTR */
    __HAL_PCD_CLEAR_FLAG(hpcd, USB_ISTR_ESOF); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In STM32 F7 you can detect disconnection in function `void HAL_PCD_SuspendCallback(PCD_HandleTypeDef *hpcd)`, in file usbd_conf.c. I hope it will be the same in L4.

Comment: He did not mention the HAL.

Comment: JMA, I'll update with IRQ Handler of PCD. Peter, the HAL is the generated by STM32CubeMX.

Comment: I'm sorry @Silas, that was something that had pointed but now I don't have the HW to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your stm32, but I use `STM32CubeMX` to generate codes, my board is "stm32f4", and I have a file named "usb_host.c". In this file, I have a function:

```
static void USBH_UserProcess  (USBH_HandleTypeDef *phost, uint8_t id)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CALL_BACK_1 */
  switch(id)
  {
  case HOST_USER_SELECT_CONFIGURATION:
  break;

  case HOST_USER_DISCONNECTION:
  Appli_state = APPLICATION_DISCONNECT;
  break;

  case HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE:
      printf("READY\n");
  Appli_state = APPLICATION_READY;
  break;

  case HOST_USER_CONNECTION:
  Appli_state = APPLICATION_START;
  break;

  default:
  break;
  }
  /* USER CODE END CALL_BACK_1 */
}
```

### **It's done.**

---

If you want your own callback:

```
static void USBH_UserProcess  (USBH_HandleTypeDef *phost, uint8_t id)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CALL_BACK_1 */
    FATFS_USBcallback(phost, id);
  /* USER CODE END CALL_BACK_1 */
}
```

And in another file:

```
void (*__usbChangedCallback)(ApplicationTypeDef) = NULL;

void FATFS_setStateChangedCallback(void (*callback)(ApplicationTypeDef)){
    __usbChangedCallback = callback;
}

void FATFS_USBcallback(USBH_HandleTypeDef *phost, uint8_t id){
    
    switch(id){
        case HOST_USER_SELECT_CONFIGURATION:
        break;
        case HOST_USER_DISCONNECTION:
            state = APPLICATION_DISCONNECT;
        break;
        case HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE:
            FATFS_PRINTF("APPLICATION_READY\n");
            state = APPLICATION_READY;
            break;
        case HOST_USER_CONNECTION:
            FATFS_PRINTF("APPLICATION_START\n");
            state = APPLICATION_START;
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    
    if(__usbChangedCallback != NULL)
        __usbChangedCallback(state);
}
```

Implement your own callback:

```
void myCallback(ApplicationTypeDef state){
    //bla bla bla
}
```

And after that, do it anywhere you need to:

```
FATFS_setStateChangedCallback(myCallback);
```

Enjoy.